# Unable to identify proposed changes in documentation review

Tags: discussion, documentation, proposed-changes

There is the following proposed change in documentation: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/33616, in which I can not find what are the changes that the user made. Everything seems identical. The description says:

> added 5 versions

[image]

The only change I can see is at the version (red circle).

Am I missing something? Should we improve the way that version changes are displayed in the review?

Answer (score 1):

I did the same thing.  As it turns out, the version IS the change.  What the change is saying is that this applies to C# versions 2-6 (as opposed to versions 5-6, which is what it was before the proposed change).

This is actually what brought me here--I came across [one for Enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/51273?draftId=43732) (See screenshot).  I had thought that those version numbers were talking about the documentation revision or something like that so, after clicking around and not seeing any other green or red, I assumed that perhaps we were talking about the summary itself since that's the only thing that was expanded when I entered.  I clicked "Approve" because the summary looked acceptable to me, but then I got a message that the change had already been rejected by someone else and the reason had nothing to do with the summary I was reading. It took me a while to figure out what was going on.

I think the problem is that those numbers that indicate C# versions are not obvious in meaning unless you already know what they mean.  I think the site would be improved if it were more explicit (like it should say "C# versions 2.0-6.0" rather than just "2.0-6.0").  That would turn this question into a feature request...

[image]